# Flex item overflowing container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

In the code below, Foo is fixed height. The bar should take the rest of the space vertically. But the bar is overflowing, taking up more the rest vertically, and there is always a scroll bar.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.foo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  This is Foo.
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <iframe id="simple" src="simple.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I put the code you were given in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8b23mnh7/ - Not seeing the issue you are from the code you gave.

Comment: I think you have to add some reset css like normalize to reset all default margins.

Comment: There are no such problem in your code

Comment: Updated. It is an iframe inside the bar, not simple text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML elements are `height: auto` by default. You need to define full height if that's the space you want to use. ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276))

Then you need to remove the default margins from the `body` element.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;           /* NEW */
  margin: 0;               /* NEW */
}

.foo {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.bar {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

iframe {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">This is Foo.</div>
<div class="bar"><iframe id="simple" src="simple.html"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: adding height: 100vh; margin: 0;  to body did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Sunnyday add `display:block` to iframe and tell me if it fixes your issue with your initial code

Comment: @Sunnyday you need to all consider `box-sizing:border-box` for the borders